# Would have + pp question

Tags: would

Adele recently posted sth on Instagram. Apparently, she has cancelled two concerts and she is explaining why

In that post she says : I'm sorry for the nights you WOULD HAVE HAD with your loved ones and the memories you WOULD HAVE MADE together.

Now, I know she is talking hypothetically but what confuses me is whether she is talking about a hypothetical scenario in the FUTURE or in the PAST?

We normally use would have + pp for past time but in this case , the time of the concerts cancelled seem to not have passed since she says "I'm unable to perform over the weekend".

Comment: I don't know who Adele is, but meseems her English is faulty. One can be sorry *for* someone else or *for* doing something bad. And yes, the Past Perfect seems wrong here as well. *If she had not canceled that concert her fans would have a great night tommow*.

Comment: She means that you would (otherwise could look back and) have had enjoyable nights and memories with them in the scenario where the concerts took place.

Comment: Although no tweet should fairly be expected to be flawless -- therefore not usually for modeling -- Adele's lyrics have the power to get to the point using language of the street.  That and her voice, humility, and catchy melodies explain the place she has taken.

Comment: She's talking about a hypothetical situation in the future. And you really can't fault her for not saying "the nights you would be going to have had."

Comment: @peter shor - so is it grammatically correct? We can use would have pp for a hypothetical scenario in the future or is it one of those things that native speaking people use but  technically wrong?

Comment: @AntonioConte: I can't think of any reasonable alternatives to describe this type of future hypothetical situation. I don't know whether the *Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* or similar references say about this. We don't have *un Académie anglaise*, so there's no real authority about what's grammatical in English.

Comment: @AntonioConte: And one more point: for some ***other*** types of hypothetical future scenarios, *would have pp.* is wrong.

Comment: It seems to me Adele is talking about events that would have taken place (in the past, as of now) had she not concelled her concerts.  Consider: If you had been at Lake Tahoe for the Fourth of July, I'm sure you would have enjoyed the fire works.